RS485 collision detection
Using the ADM2861E transceiver we want to detect RS485 collisions by reading the transmit echo (receiver is always enabled) and compare what was received to what was send. If not equal there may be a collision and we want to retry sending.
Problem is that we always receive what we send even though there is a collision and the message on the RS485 bus gets corrupted.
In the image below; node1 (using ADM2861E) receives erroneously what was send by node1 while node2 (using MAX13442) receives the corrupted message correctly?

This is not what I expected.  What can be done to receive the corrupted message to detect the collision like node2 instead?

RS485 is not a good choice if you don't have bus management protocol. I'd suggest to either implement that (could be as simple as time slicing) or use CAN for its native collision handling. Just how many nodes do you have? If only two then full-duplex transport protocol is the simplest solution.

It seems to me that your bus management is faulty.

When two transmitters transmit a different level simultaneously, one high and one low, then the bus will be in some state.
That state could be anything, as one driver may be stronger than the other driver. The stronger driver might overwrite the whole bus to some state for both receivers, so only one receiver will see something that does not match what it drives, and other driver will always see what it drives to bus.
Different receivers may have different thresholds and hysteresis levels, and they are at different parts of the bus wires.
With voltages near the switching threshold, some may have switched over to the incorrect state and some not.
Bus wires have some non-zero resistance so it could be that with two drivers on bus, the received state seen by third observer may depend on if it is more near to driver 1 or driver 2.
Basically, with two drivers driving the bus, each driver only sees it's own wires for reception, so any resistance on the bus or in the driver outputs has an effect, so stronger may always win and always see what it drives to bus and never see collisions, and possibly neither will never see collisions from it's own wires.

"possibly neither will never see collisions from it's own wires" is often the case with long busses.
